# MongoDB available connections

Tags: sql-server, mongodb, database-connection

I installed MongoDB on Windows, Mac and Linux.
I run MongoDB with all default arguments and I enter a command `db.serverStatus().connections` on mongo to check the available connections.

Here is my observation, Windows 7 has 19999, Mac has only 203 and Linux has 818. Therefore, I would like to ask what makes the number of available connections different and is it possible to increase the available connections?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

For UNIX-like systems (i.e. Linux and OS X), the connection limit is governed by [ulimits](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/ulimit/). MongoDB will use 80% of the available file descriptors for connections, which is why you see 203 on Mac (~80% of 256) and 819 on Linux (~80% of 1024).

The MongoDB documentation includes [recommended settings](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/ulimit/#recommended-settings) for production systems. Typically you wouldn't need to change this on development environments, but you will see a warning on startup if the connection limits are considered low.

In MongoDB 2.4 and earlier, there is a hard-coded maximum of 20,000 connections per server irrespective of the ulimits. This maximum has been removed as at MongoDB 2.6.

There is also a [`maxConns`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/configuration-options/#maxConns) MongoDB configuration directive that can be used to limit the connections to something *lower* than what would be allowed by ulimits.

Answer (score 0):

@fmchan Turn off SELinux and check again.

I set high NOFile and NProc limits on systemd, and in /etc/security/limits.conf file. But, it didn't help

Now, the only thing that works for me is to
1. setenforce 0 && systemctl restart mongod.service
2. Write a SELinux policy to allow mongod_exec_t to setrlimit and rlimitinh

Here's a similar issue https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=1415045

Answer (score 0):

I was facing the same issue and apparently ulimit -n 6000 didn't help.

On macos we could check the setting for open files using below command which was showing 256 in my case and 80% of 256 was 204 hence the max connection by mongo was 204.

```
launchctl limit maxfiles
```

I have followed https://gist.github.com/tombigel/d503800a282fcadbee14b537735d202c to resolve my error. This explains in details how to set the values.

Follow the documentation, restart laptop and you should see the setting