# Very high number of connections to MongoDB

Tags: mongodb

I have a local app that connects to a local MongoDB. It has 2 databases and about 60 collections in total.

I open one connection and then get an object to access each collection.

I let the system run the whole afternoon and checking stats, I found this:

[image]

I don't understand why I have over 750k connections; but also, I don't really understand the metrics; for example the number blow: total connections created, hovering at 1770...

Can someone explain what is going on?

Comment: what application you are connecting to the database? What kind of metrics/dashboard you are using to generate the reports?

Comment: I'm using Studio3T

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Total Connections Created** refers to the number of times the server has accepted a connection since it started running, so if it has been running for many months, it is likely to have many. It doesn't mean they are still active (and most won't be).

You can choose to only show active connections under **Current Connections** by clicking on the menu icon and choosing In Use:

[image: Current Connections in Studio 3T]

Here's more info on why you might be seeing a large number of available connections: [MongoDB available connections](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22375027/mongodb-available-connections)